# Copy the property values to another object with C#

Tags: c#

To copy the property values from one object to another, we usually achieve with following syntax:

```
ca.pro1 = cb.pro2;
ca.pro2 = cb.pro2;
```

where ca and cb are of the same class.

Is there any **simpler synatx or utility method** to help us to achieve the same effect?

Thank you.

Comment: This is what you're looking for: [Cloning objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c)

Comment: Cloning is not the same as copying in the context of this question: The OP doesn't say it is okay to instantiate an object. The answers provided here are useful and distinct from the answers found under "cloning" questions.

Answer (score 58):

```
public static void CopyPropertiesTo<T, TU>(this T source, TU dest)
{
    var sourceProps = typeof (T).GetProperties().Where(x => x.CanRead).ToList();
    var destProps = typeof(TU).GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.CanWrite)
            .ToList();

    foreach (var sourceProp in sourceProps)
    {
        if (destProps.Any(x => x.Name == sourceProp.Name))
        {
            var p = destProps.First(x => x.Name == sourceProp.Name);
            if(p.CanWrite) { // check if the property can be set or no.
                p.SetValue(dest, sourceProp.GetValue(source, null), null);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why `if(p.CanWrite)`? destProps  are already of CanWrite type.

Comment: You can optimize like this :

        `var p = destProps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == sourceProp.Name);`
        `if (p != null)`
`p.SetValue(dest, sourceProp.GetValue(source, null), null);`

Answer (score 15):

If I am not mistaken with what is required, the way to easily achieve **property value copy between two existing instances** (even not of the same type) is to use  [Automapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/).

1. create mapping configuration
2. and then call .Map(soure, target)

As long as you keep property in same type and in same naming convention, all should work.

Example:

```
MapperConfiguration _configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cnf =>
            {
                cnf.CreateMap<SourceType, TargetType>();
            });
var mapper = new Mapper(_configuration);
maper.DefaultContext.Mapper.Map(source, target)
```

Answer (score 12):

This is a function that I used to copy members between models in ASP.NET MVC. While you seek a code that work for the same type, this code will also support other types that has the same properties.

It uses reflections, but in a more clean manner. Beware of the `Convert.ChangeType`: you might not need it; you could do a check on the type instead of converting.

```
public static TConvert ConvertTo<TConvert>(this object entity) where TConvert : new()
{
    var convertProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(TConvert)).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();
    var entityProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(entity).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();

    var convert = new TConvert();

    foreach (var entityProperty in entityProperties)
    {
        var property = entityProperty;
        var convertProperty = convertProperties.FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.Name == property.Name);
        if (convertProperty != null)
        {
            convertProperty.SetValue(convert, Convert.ChangeType(entityProperty.GetValue(entity), convertProperty.PropertyType));
        }
    }

    return convert;
}
```

Since this is an extension method, the usage is simple:

```
var result = original.ConvertTo<SomeOtherType>();
```

Comment: PropertyDescriptor.SetValue didn't work for me, had to use var convertProperties = typeof(TConvert).GetProperties(); - which gives you a List of PropertyInfo instead of PropertyDescriptor's

Comment: In Hindsight: "didn't work" meaning, the code ran, but it did not set any values, for example bool properties, b/c they had private setters (D'oh!).

Comment: This didnt work for me either, getting Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]

Comment: @Jean-Paul It seem to fail when using nullable type. I invite you to find a solution and update this post. Or you should seek an existing library like Automapper.

Answer (score 3):

not really. there is a [MemberwiseClone()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) but that copies references directly meaning you would get a reference to the same object and that can be bad. You can implement the [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) interface and use that for a deep copy. I prefer making my own Clone() method though because the ICloneable interface returns an Object that needs to be cast.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with ICloneable, it is impossible to properly implement it because the interface doesn't allow the caller to indicate what he means by "clone".

Comment: i believe the de facto standard is a deep clone, but that also goes with what i said about making your own clone method, for better type safety, etc.

Comment: MemberwiseClone is not applicable to this question. It always creates a new object; this question is about updating fields in an **existing object**, from another object.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static TTarget Convert<TSource, TTarget>(TSource sourceItem)
{
    if (null == sourceItem)
    {
        return default(TTarget);
    }

    var deserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace,  };

    var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sourceItem, deserializeSettings);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TTarget>(serializedObject);
}
```

usage:

```
  promosion = YourClass.Convert<Promosion, PromosionExtension>(existsPromosion);
```