# How to copy from List<a> to list<b> using reflection? C#

Tags: c#, list, reflection

Both object are "the same" but its imposible for me, to copy de object definition directly.

The class A looks like:

```
public class A { 
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="MyPROP")]
    List<Namespace.Property> pro {get; set;}
}
```

The class B looks like:

```
public class B { 
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="MyNewPropertyName")]
    List<MyNames.Property> pro {get; set;}
}
```

As you can see, the only differences are attributes and namespace, both classes has the same methods and properties.

The error I'm getting using reflection is this

> El objeto de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[Namespace.Property]' no puede convertirse en el tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[MyNames.Property]'.

Comment: Reflection solution will be much more complex and extra-work, can i suggest another approach, like Serialization or it a must ?

Comment: `Namespace.Property` and `MyNames.Property` are different types.  Why do you think you should be able to convert one to another?  Do they have similar properties?

Comment: See [Copy the property values to another object with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3445784) and also [tag:automapper].  But since you are using Json.NET apparently, a quick approach might be to do a serialization round-trip like so: `a.pro = JToken.FromObject(b.pro).ToObject<List<Namespace.Property>>();`

Comment: Serialization is not an option, becuase the JsonProperty attribute.
@dbc they have similar properties (they are differetn just because its namespaces)

Comment: Need to see a [mcve].  But maybe this would help: [How to ignore JsonProperty(PropertyName = “someName”) when serializing json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20622492).

Comment: @dbc can you give an example of how to make it with automapper please? :D

Comment: C# doesn't use duck-typing so just because the methods and properties are the same it doesn't make the classes compatible. You have to instantiate new objects to change the type of an object in C#.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Reflection is a lot of extra work, you can achieve a solution without it. In case reflection isn't a must, here is a few options.

**Serialization:** Serializing source object and Deserializing into another, using *StringSerialization*(*Json* or *Xml*).

Here is [Brian Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20639697/303254) code on another question, that ignores *JsonPropertyAttribute*.

```
class LongNameContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        // Let the base class create all the JsonProperties 
        // using the short names
        IList<JsonProperty> list = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        // Now inspect each property and replace the 
        // short name with the real property name
        foreach (JsonProperty prop in list)
        {
            prop.PropertyName = prop.UnderlyingName;
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

**AutoMapper:** Mapping the inner classes, and if your properties are the same, you can skip manually mapping the entire classes.

[Complete Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oGrfgo)

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<A, B>().ReverseMap());

var objA = new A
{
    Prop = new List<AClass>
    {
        new AClass { Name = "Magneto" },
        new AClass { Name = "Wolverine" }
    }
};

var objB = Mapper.Map<B>(objA);
Console.WriteLine(objB.Prop[0].Name);
Console.WriteLine(objB.Prop[1].Name);
```

Comment: Serialization does the trick, but avoiding the "PropertyName" attribute as @dbc said. Thanks Orel, and dbc, if some day I see you, I will invite the beers.

Comment: Added a solution that force ignore on JsonPropertyAttribute.

Comment: I have no idea why this answer gets downvoted, I would appreciate if someone will write explaining comment why their choose to do so.